# Crontab will not launch a Node.js app via a shell script

Tags: bash, cron

I have following shell script that checks whether a Node.js app (luminati) is running. If not, it attempts to restart. I have confirmed that my shell script works properly on a standalone basis.

However If I add this script on my crontab, it executes at expected intervals but fails to launch the node app. It basically is not executing the second last line of the script `luminati &`

```
#!/bin/bash
procno=$(pgrep -f luminati | wc -l);
echo  "process found: $procno"
if [ "$procno" == "4" ];then
    echo "Luminati is Running. No action taken"
else
    echo "Restarting Luminati"
    luminati &
fi
```

what is the problem here?

Comment: Your PATH maybe?

Comment: What does the email sent by cron tell you about the error?

Comment: It is a node global install. So I would expect it to work from anywhere. But I am not an expert

Comment: I am not seeing any mail. I remember getting emails in the past from cron but not for this.

Comment: BTW, that `==` should be `=`. The former is a misguided attempt by bash to ease programmer life with POSIX incompatible operators.

Comment: Okay, to diagnose the environment, what if you run your script from the command line with `env -i HOME=$HOME /path/to/script`?

Comment: Hmm. Any program started by cron and writing to stdout (like you do with echo "process found") MUST send an email. Either your cron, your email config, or your crontab line is fishy/broken.

Comment: Run `which luminati` in Terminal to get its full path, then use that in `cron` job.

Comment: I tried putting the full path `/usr/local/bin/luminati` in the shell script. Again, the shell script was able to execute when I called from ubuntu prompt. But in cron, it failed. This time however, I directed the output of the script to a text file and I am seeing this error message `Luminati proxy manager requires Node.js V6.
Please upgrade your Node using nvm or nave, or visit nodejs.org and download a newer version.
After that run the following command to reinstall Luminati Proxy Manager:`. So it is showing a different behavior and is thinking that I want to install this app.

Comment: BTW, I have node v 9.4.0 on my system

Comment: `set | grep LD` from your terminal will possible emit 1-n var=value pairs. Add those to the top of you script, each preceded with `export`. If it still doesn't work, there there must be another env-Var in you terminal environment that is needed. Look at unfiltered output of `set` and add any relevant var=value pairs to your script. Good luck.

Comment: Read the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) for the [tag:cron] tag.

Comment: @shellter, you may be onto something here. I am looking into the env variable that are needed for this app